# How to add separate scroll for each row and I want sorting at nested level in ag-grid-react

Tags: reactjs, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

**I am using ag-grid with react**

[image]

I want two scrollbars. for each block at the yellow line shown in the image

And I also want to sort data at nested levels so how should be the column definitions

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set up two separate tables and show them side by side. Than add a class inside the container that shows all your rows.
After that you can add

```css
table-rows1 {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table-rows2 {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 800px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Comment: I want them to be on one table so that I can manage filters and sortings easily